# Substitute a string variable into the name of an array

Tags: bash

I am trying to substitute a string variable (an array here), but I am getting an error. Could anyone suggest how to solve this?

```
COMP="MY"

MY_common_sections_to_fix=( \
      ".rodata" \
      ".data" \
      )

 echo ${${COMP}_common_sections_to_fix[@]}
```

ERROR:

${${COMP}_common_sections_to_fix[@]}: bad substitution

Comment: Which version of bash? There's a convenient builtin available in 4.4.

Comment: Since the array you initialized is `MY_common_sections_to_fix` but you are trying to access `L1CC_common_sections_to_fix`, that's one level of non-surprise.  However, the dynamic naming of variables is also problematic.  You could create a variable holding `MY_common_sections_to_fix` and work out how to exploit `${!varname[@]}` or thereabouts — untested, but `${!var}` references the variable with the name stored in `$var`.  (Semi-tested: the results do not look promising.  Assume that it won't work until further notice!)

Comment: Further notice: it won't work — see [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the Bash manual.  It looks like you can't do indirect expansion of array names.

Comment: [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Evaluating_indirect.2Freference_variables) goes into which tricks for indirect reference are available on which shells, and which apply to arrays. Note the caveats given attached to the last example in the section as an example of how error-prone doing this in a shell without the pertinent features can be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is indirectly reference an array.

A nameref, if you have a new enough shell (4.3 or later), is the most appropriate tool for the job:

```
COMP=MY
MY_common_sections_to_fix=( .rodata .data )
declare -n active_sections=${COMP}_common_sections_to_fix
printf '%s\n' "${active_sections[@]}"
```

This makes `active_sections` an alias for `MY_common_sections_to_fix`, and properly emits `.rodata` and `.data` as output.

---

If you *don't* have bash 4.3 available, hackery with `eval` is an available (albeit unfortunate) option:

```
printf -v cmd '%q=( "${%q[@]}" )' active_sections "${COMP}_common_sections_to_fix"
eval "$cmd"
```

Comment: Eh, they used "MY" in the variable name in the question. They use both values, that means either is equally correct -- one or the other needs to be modified to generate a working example.

Comment: I thought they were trying to make it `L1CC_common_sections_to_fix`, but maybe not. The first command works with 3.x if I take out the `-n` option.

Comment: @l'L'l,  eh? In 3.x, I get `declare -- active_sections="MY_common_sections_to_fix"` as the result if the `-n` is removed -- meaning only the *name* of the target variable, and not its value, is available.

Comment: Actually I have no clue what the OP is trying to do, so +1 for trying to make any sense from it.